# window.open not not able to open more than two links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As per my requirement, i need to create a Google Chrome Extension which opens multiple links (25+) on a single click in different tabs of a single chrome window. The code was working fine earlier till the Chrome 18. Now, I am using chrome 24 and that code stopped working. I was simply storing all the links in an array and opening them using a for loop as follows:

```
  for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
  {
    var tablink = links[i];
    if(links[i] != "")
    {
            tablink = *"somedomain"* + tablink;
        setTimeout(window.open(tablink), 500);  
    }
  }
```

As a result, only two links were open in tabs and rest will open in different chrome windows. What should i do to overcome this?

Edit #1

In my manifest file

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["script.js", "jquery.js", "dialog.js"]
    }
  ],


"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
```

The code given first is in dialog.js

Comment: If this really is an extension, why aren't you using the [tab api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)?

Comment: `I need to open multiple links (25+) on a single click` 25 tabs opened at the same time... o.O

Comment: i have tried using chrome.tabs.create({"url":tablink}); but it won't worked

Comment: i tried this window.open("http://www.google.co.in/");window.open("https://www.facebook.com/");
   window.open("https://www.yahoo.com/");
   window.open("https://www.in.com/"); but it did not open on new window?

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena can you share code for chrome.tabs.create({"url":tablink});, it worked for me?

Comment: @Sudarshan ... in which page you have used this code, like in backgroung page, background script or else

Comment: @Sudarshan ... have you tried running your code from within a loop

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena : It is in content scripts, yes i tried running it in loop; Show your code it speaks better.

Comment: @Sudarshan ... you can check in the edit now

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena tried the same able to open 50 + windows here...

Comment: @Sudarshan ... check my permissions value in manifest file. Is it correct?

Comment: @Sudarshan .. try reading urls from a file and then open them.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena: Permission are good, if permissions have gone wrong you would have not seen a window at all;what difference does url(reading from file etc) for window.open() make; Can you try this code and let me know results; for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(window.open("http://www.google.co.in/"),500);
setTimeout(window.open("https://www.facebook.com/"),500);
setTimeout(window.open("https://www.yahoo.com/"),500);
setTimeout(window.open("https://www.gaana.com/"),500);
setTimeout(window.open("https://www.youtube.com/"),500);}

Comment: first two links opened in tabs and rest in different windows. Could it be a problem with chrome version?

Comment: I am on linux 
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got the solution, hit n trial rocks :)

I just removed setTimeout function and it works. I still don't why it was causing the problem.

```
for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
  {
    var tablink = links[i];
    if(links[i] != "")
    {
            tablink = *"somedomain"* + tablink;
        window.open(tablink);  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common error in JavaScript.
`setTimeout(window.open(tablink), 500);` means to invoke what window.open *returns* after 500 milliseconds. The return value of window.open is typically a Window object, which makes setTimeout fail and your code stops executing. That's what caused the problem.
Please use `setTimeout(function(){window.open(tablink)}, 500);` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to open number of sites at the same time,

found that "pop-ups were blocked on that page "

you can see that in address-bar.

:)

Comment: check address bar and click always allow pop-ups radio-button