# How to download multiple files with window.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to download multiple files at once. At first I use `window.location = url` but now it doesn't seem to work.

I've changed it to `window.open(url, "_blank")` and it only downloads the first one:

```
window.open("/host/Controller/DownloadDasFiles?paramId=204");
window.open("/host/Controller/DownloadDasFiles?paramId=205");
window.open("/host/Controller/DownloadDasFiles?paramId=206");
```

```csharp
public FileResult DownloadDasFiles(int paramId)
{
  var dasControl = UnityConfig.container.Resolve<IDasControlService>();
  var filename = dasControl.GetDasFileToDownload(paramId);
  return File(filename, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(filename));
}
```

In my real case I do this after AJAX success in a javascript loop, but this code should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: The problem is because the browser will stop you spamming the user by opening multiple tabs/windows in quick succession. If you need to do this, I'd suggest a better solution would be to zip up the files on the server and start a single download to that zip file.

Comment: Better to return a ZIP file containing all downloaded files rather than executing `window.open` multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671760/download-multiple-files-selected-with-mvc5 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713710/returning-multiple-files-from-mvc-action.

Comment: Thanks, returning a ZIP is what I'm developing now. I suspected something like that, thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.open not not able to open more than two links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467915/window-open-not-not-able-to-open-more-than-two-links)

Answer (score 0):

This may help. It will open all 3 windows at same time.

```
let test = [204, 205, 206];
let downLoadFileBaseUrl = '/host/Controller/DownloadDasFiles?paramId='
test.forEach(element => {
  let file = `${downLoadFileBaseUrl}+${element}`;
  window.open(file, '_blank', 'File :' + element + ',scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
});
```